# Designing back plate for Ring Doorbell

Tags: 3d-design

What is a good tool to use to design a back plate for a Ring Doorbell?  The shape will essentially be a wedge shape, tilting the doorbell to the side and down a bit.  I'll need to iterate over a few prints, so want to be able to tweak it as I go.

I've found TinkerCAD doesn't let me adjust shape sizes, stretching one axis but not the other.

Comment: StackExchange has a policy against asking questions that are "primarily opinion-based" (explained in the [help center](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)) because they often don't result in very good answers (since everybody will just post a one-liner with their personal favorite CAD tool). Also, **don't answer questions in the comments**, please.

Answer (score 0):

If you wannwa go fully parametric, use OpenSCAD. Or you can use Autodesk Fusion 360 (which is free for non-commercial use)